# Dynamic Time Warping in Python, how to memoise a mutable matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, dynamic-programming

I created a simple implementation of Dynamic Time Warping in Python, but feel like it is a bit of a hack. I implemented the recurrence relation (or, at least, I believe I did!), but because in my case this involves a numpy array, I had to wrap it in a class to get memoisation to work (numpy arrays are mutable).

Wiki link to DTW: [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)

Here is the code:

```
class DynamicTimeWarp(object):
  def __init__(self, seq1, seq2):
    self.warp_matrix = self.time_warp_matrix(seq1, seq2)

  def time_warp_matrix(self, seq1, seq2):
    output = np.zeros((len(seq1), len(seq2)), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(len(seq1)):
      for j in range(len(seq2)):
        output[i][j] = np.sqrt((seq1[i] - seq2[j]) ** 2)
    return output·

  @lru_cache(maxsize=100)
  def warp_path(self, i=None, j=None):
    if (i is None) and (j is None):
      i, j = self.warp_matrix.shape
      i   -= 1
      j   -= 1

    distance = self.warp_matrix[i, j]
    path = ((i, j),)
    if i == j == 0:
      return distance, path

    potential = []

    if i - 1 >= 0:
      potential.append(self.warp_path(i-1, j))

    if j - 1 >= 0:
      potential.append(self.warp_path(i, j-1))

    if (j - 1 >= 0) and (i - 1 >=0):
      potential.append(self.warp_path(i-1, j-1))

    if len(potential) > 0:
      new_dist, new_path = min(potential, key = lambda x: x[0])
      distance          += new_dist
      path               = new_path + path

    return distance, path
```

My questions:

1. Is this a valid implementation of DTW, as I believe?
2. Is there a better way to do this while maintaining the use of numpy arrays
   and the recurrence relation?
3. If I end up having to use a class, and then wish to reuse an instance of the class (by passing it new sequences, and recalculating the warp_matrix), I will have to have some kind of dummy value passed as an argument to the warp_path function - as otherwise I imagine lru_cache will incorrectly return values. Is there some more elegant way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

While it is easy to think of DTW as a recursive function, it is possible to implement a iterative version.  The iterative version is typically 10 to 30 times faster.

eamonn